# Is JPA locking considered atomic?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0, eclipselink

I am using Eclipse Link implementation, but maybe this is relevant also for Hibernate.
At some point I called:

`em.lock(entity, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);`

Which I considered as an atomic operation.

Surprisingly - after putting a breakpoint on the `@Version` field, it seems that there many calls to `entity._persistence_get` and `entity._persistence_set`.

Apparently - it is possible to get to the same point with a debugger, using two browsers, and switch between the Threads while it is still running those hidden functions. When this is done - it's impossible for both threads to flush/commit later.

Is there a change this would happen when not on Release Mode, or is it only because of the debugger?

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by atomic? An attached entity is not supposed to be used in several threads.

Comment: Atomic=no context switch is allowed during the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way (AFAIK) to prevent context switches in Java. Thus, I don't see how locking could be atomic in this sense. But I also don't see why it would matter anyway, since an attached entity is not supposed to be used concurrently by several threads.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this from happen? If two users are trying to update the same field at the same time - how can one prevent it from happen? I thought locking was the only solution.

Comment: locking is used to prevent concurrent modifications of a row **in database**. It has nearly nothing to do with threads: two transactions might be running on two different JVMs. The incrementation of the version field caused by the lock will make one of the two concurrent transactions rollback with an exception. But thread context switching doesn't have any influence on the mechanism. Read http://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and for an explanation.